# @media Unknown on IE11

Tags: html, css, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

The media querys aren't working for my web page aren't working in IE11.
So I thought I would create a simple test HTML page.
It still fails in IE11 - even though it works in Chrome and Firefox and on Android browsers.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'><html>
<head>
<title>Foo</title>
<style type="text/css">

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:56px;color:#0f0;}
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:9px;color:#00f;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

IE just ignores all styling and inspecting the code it has replaced the style in the inspection window with:

```
<STYLE type=text/css>
@media Unknown    
{
H1 {
    FONT-SIZE: 56px; COLOR: #0f0
}
H1 {
    FONT-SIZE: 9px; COLOR: #00f
}

}
</STYLE>
```

I have even tried:

```
@media all and (min-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:56px;color:#0f0;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:9px;color:#00f;}
}
```

...and also....

```
@media all (min-device-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:56px;color:#0f0;}
}

@media (max-device-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:9px;color:#00f;}
}
```

...and...

```
@media all (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:1920) {
  h1 {font-size:56px;color:#0f0;}
}

@media all (max-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:9px;color:#00f;}
}
```

The PC I am testing the code on has two screens attached....
is this why IE can't determine the Media??

Very annoying. Can't stand IE.
If anyone can shed some light on why the CSS won't work on IE, I would be very grateful.

Comment: No one should be using that doctype for new web pages since 1999. Why are you using it?

Comment: True - the html is used in a Microsoft HTML control - which auto-generated the doctype. I did try it with different doctypes too.....Outside of the control I hasten to add.

Comment: Doctypes are not something you swap around. It's the first thing you put on a page and it never, under any circumstances, changes. All new web pages are required to have the one used in the accepted answer and no other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my code with updated doctype and html tags

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Foo</title>
<style type="text/css">

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:56px;color:#0f0;}
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  h1 {font-size:9px;color:#00f;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for that. I tried it - but still same result. I did try it with different doctypes previously too.

Comment: May be you are using old version of IE, or have some plugin installed on IE. I have tested in IE. Its working.

Comment: https://www.excelautoparts.com/testie.html

I have changed the doctype to HTML 5.

IE11 no longer shows 'Unknown' but the CSS still seems to be ignored.

I read somewhere that you can't have two declarations for the same element. But that doesn't seem to make sense. ??

(After changing the doctype the Document mode in the Emulation tab has changed from IE7 to Edge).

Comment: What do size / colour do you see 'Test' in?

Comment: Definitely IE11.

Comment: May be it is the two screens issue??

Comment: Working now. Needed the doctype to be correct and @media all and (min-width:640px). Was testing the code locally which was forcing IE to emaultae IE7. Now running on the Web with the correct doctype (thanks user123) and (funnily enough the correct CSS) - it works. The IE11 defaulting to IE7 when running local code threw me.

Comment: How do I close this question? Do I need to close it - or is that it now?? Oh such a newbie.

Comment: @Edward mark the answer (*not comment*) that helped you solve the issue as the accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I am glade to see its working in IE, please accept answer and up-vote.

Comment: Thanks for your help user123

Comment: I have accepted your answer - but since I am new to the forum and have 0 reputation - it won't publically show any score for your answer user123. Sorry about that,